# is there any way to show discount directly on products page on shopify online store by using discount app?

Tags: node.js, shopify

I have created one discount app on shopify platform , but that discount is displaying inside cart or chectout section, need way to show discounts on products page on online store.

discount app created but shows inside cart or checkout section.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.